# Optimising a large Insert Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (Test and Prod) and have a stored procedure which run each day to insert rows in Test which dont exist in Prod.

At the moment it is just a simple insert like below:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ('Field1','Field2','Field3','Field4')
SELECT 'Field1','Field2','Field3','Field4' 
FROM Table2
WHERE Table2.Field1 NOT IN (SELECT Table1.Field1 FROM Table1)
```

The issue is that the tables have alot of rows and this takes a very long time to run. Is there a better/ more efficient way to write this?

Comment: Have you tried MERGE? Not sure how it would perform, you would need to test. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: +1 for MERGE, this should perform best.

Comment: Before you try to speed things up, find out where the bottleneck is. The problem may not lie with the query.

Comment: @dnoeth..Hadn't ever used Merge before. Results were great. Knocked about an hour off the time. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Create an index on Field1 on both tables.
Besides that, I don't see how this could be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4)
SELECT t2.Field1, t2.Field2, t2.Field3, t2.Field4 
FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON (t1.Field1 = t2.Field1)
WHERE t1.Field1 IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ('Field1','Field2','Field3','Field4')
SELECT 'Field1','Field2','Field3','Field4' 
FROM Table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t1.Field1 FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.Field1 = t2.Field1)
```